# Using @ElementCollection not working on GAE with JPA 2

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I'm moving from JPA 1 to JPA 2 in my Gooogle App Engine project, and for that I changed the annotations for collections of enums, like this case:

```
//  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // JPA 1
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=PositioningType.class)
    private List<PositioningType> bestPositionings;
```

`PositioningType` is an enum that is not annotated.

That code is giving me the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The MetaData for the element class "com.olympya.datamodel.model.PositioningType" of the collection field "com.olympya.datamodel.model.Player.bestPositionings" was not found.
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityTransaction.commit(JPAEntityTransaction.java:122)
at com.olympya.Services.mergeUser(Services.java:102)
...
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: The MetaData for the element class "com.olympya.datamodel.model.PositioningType" of the collection field "com.olympya.datamodel.model.Player.bestPositionings" was not found.
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.AbstractFKStore.<init>(AbstractFKStore.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.<init>(FKListStore.java:83)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.newFKListStore(DatastoreManager.java:472)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getBackingStoreForCollection(MappedStoreManager.java:798)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getBackingStoreForField(MappedStoreManager.java:709)
at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

I'm having the same exception when trying to persist a collection of Integers:

```
@ElementCollection
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value = "true")
//private List<PositioningType> bestPositionings = new ArrayList<PositioningType>();
private List<Integer> bestPositionings;
```

Results in:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: The MetaData for the element class "java.lang.Integer" of the collection field "com.olympya.datamodel.model.Player.bestPositionings" was not found.
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.AbstractFKStore.<init>(AbstractFKStore.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.<init>(FKListStore.java:83)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.newFKListStore(DatastoreManager.java:472)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getBackingStoreForCollection(MappedStoreManager.java:798)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getBackingStoreForField(MappedStoreManager.java:709)
at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:99)
```

The metadata for **Integer** was not found!!!

---

**UPDATE 2**

Annotating the field with `@Basic`, and nothing else, made it work correctly. Still waiting for an answer here, though, since `@ElementCollection` should work and `@Basic` shouldn't be used on collections.

Comment: Have a look at this other question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177009/persisting-elementcollection-of-embeddable-google-app-engine-datanucleus