# Persisting @ElementCollection of @Embeddable (Google App Engine, datanucleus)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I am trying to persist a JPA entity with a collection of custom @Embeddable objects using the JPA2 [@ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) annotation. Simple example (both classes are enhanced by datanucleus):

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<TestEmbeddable> testEmbeddables;

    public Set<TestEmbeddable> testEmbeddables() {
        return this.testEmbeddables;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class TestEmbeddable implements Serializable {
    public String s;
}
```

The persisted Datastore entity, however, will only contain a collection of null values instead of the actual objects:

```
TestEntity.testEmbeddables = [null, null, ...]
```

Persisting a collection of basic types such as Strings or embedding a single TestEmbeddable object using @Embedded works perfectly fine. **Would someone be able to clarify whether element collections of embeddables are supported by datanucleus-appengine?**

While the datanucleus section on [JPA element collections](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/orm/one_to_many_list.html) only gives an example for a String collection, the corresponding [JDO section](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/orm/embedded.html#Collection) uses a custom embedded-only type. The [feature list](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/datastore_features.html) further states that embedded collections in general are compatible with GAE, but does not say whether custom types are supported. I also found one other person claiming that [this should work](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/cCUNPEOnqsw/W-ZEp7URTU0J).

**-- Edit --**

Following DataNucleus' answer, I ran some more tests:

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> stringsElementCollection;
```

--> Works. The individual Strings are persisted as TestEntity.stringsElementCollection = [str1, str2, ...]

```
@Embedded
private List<String> stringsEmbedded;
```

--> Same as @ElementCollection. I wonder if the JPA specification covers the use of [@Embedded](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) on a collection, though?

```
@ElementCollection
private List<TestEmbeddable> embeddablesElementCollection;
```

--> Doesn't work. Instead of the actual TestEmbeddable objects, the Datastore persists only a collection of null values: TestEntity.embeddablesElementCollection = [null, null, ...]

```
@Embedded
private List<TestEmbeddable> embeddablesEmbedded;
```

--> This seems to work. The TestEmbeddable.s field is stored as TestEntity.s.0, .s.1, etc. plus a TestEntity.embeddablesEmbedded.size property.

*(App Engine SDK 1.7.7.1, datanucleus 3.1.3, datanucleus-appengine 2.1.2)*

Comment: Have you tried https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/. This API encapsulates lot of things for your development.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if Google support embedded collections of such objects yet with JPA. That was only developed for JDO and works there. You could try putting a @Embedded on the embedded field to reinforce the idea that its embedded.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! While combining `@Embedded` and `@ElementCollection` doesn't work, using only `@Embedded` works, although I'm not sure in the way it's supposed to. See above for the results - does that look right to you?


Regarding the Google support you mentioned - does datanucleus-appengine need to provide explicit JPA support for this? I thought that DataNucleus abstracts from the JDO/JPA layer and that datanucleus-appengine 'only' translates DataNucleus functionality for the Datastore, regardless of whether JDO or JPA is used...

Comment: Moreover, I just noticed that the JPA implementation (probably the same for JDO?) apparently won't track changes to collections of embeddable objects, with `@Embedded` as well as with `@Lob`, if not explicitly marked as dirty. It works for Strings, though (`@ElementCollection` and `@Embedded`).

Comment: Yes their plugin has to make use of some things in metadata that only JPA has. The only other thing to say is use the latest SVN trunk of their plugin (since that hasn't been released in some time and may or may not affect things), and when having problems you report them to their issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/  since Google likely couldn't care less about monitoring some Stackoverflow tag

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been recorded by David Geiger here:
https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=318